# How to add a 1 to a phone number and remove the dashes?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, output, user-defined-functions, regexp-replace

I need the value of my data to look like this `18184789564`.

I used this code:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(+1, b.PHONE_NUMBER, '[^0-9]', '') AS PHONE_NUMBER
```

I get an error

> Numeric value is not recognized

Hopefully I can just add as simple as 1 because I was able to removed the dashes already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake uses the `CONCAT()` function for string concatenation. You have to do the concatenation with the result of `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

```
CONCAT('1', REGEXP_REPLACE(b.PHONE_NUMBER,'[^0-9]','')) AS PHONE_NUMBER
```

Comment: You freaking rock man! Thank you very much!

Comment: a shorter version of concatenation is `||`, as in:   `'1' || regexp_replace(...)`